# Cobine p-values, same data, same test, different labels

Tags: hypothesis-testing, feature-selection, combining-p-values

I have a dataset (300 samples vs 4000 features), I'm trying to extract meaningful features related to two condition `A` and `B`. Both conditions have levels 0, 1 and 2 that stand for none, mild, severe. Since features don't follow a normal distribution I used a non-parametric Kruskal test, now I have two lists of p-values `pValA` and `pValB` that contains significance levels of each feature in my dataset for condition `A` and condition `B`. How can I merge both lists and select meaningful features? I used to do the average but my supervisor faked a heart attack when he saw my code.

Comment: I don't think anything meaningful can come out of doing 4000 kruskal-wallace tests. You have massive type II error inflation issues.... If you are trying to determine which covariates are related to your conditions you should be using a hypothesis generation technique (i.e. some kind of dimensional compression) rather than t-tests, although even then it wont be able to handle the disparity between you sample size and the number of covariates you have. Can you post a sample of your data to show folks what you are working with?

Comment: I don't think I can since this is a private dataset. Another idea would be to use the feature importance of a random forest

Comment: If you can't release the data then try creating a fake set to post here (preferably one that can be directly imported into a stats program). It is very hard to help without seeing what one is dealing with. You could try a random forest but you would need to standardise the units and ensure that you do not have any overly noisy variables or they will drive your results as you have a very small number of observations relative to covariates.

Comment: Ok then, I will try to build fake data

Comment: I would try ordinal LASSO / RIDGE regression. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnetcr/vignettes/glmnetcr.pdf. It doesn't give you p-values, but in this case you shouldn't really look for them anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by merging both lists? Are you trying to combine in some way the effect of both treatments? Why would that make scientific sense?